# How to get DbContext in nested methods using Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dbcontext, simple-injector

I have a doubt since I'm new to Dependency Injection and IoC.

I have a domain layer (with business logic) and a data layer. We do not implement repositories, we use EF Core directly.
It is a Class Library project, we use it in a ASP.NET CCore Web API, WinForms, and inside another framework.

The idea is to use the same context inside a scope.

The problem is that I'm not being able to get the same context in the nested method execution, I'm sure it is because I did not understand the concept completely, can you guys give me a help on that?

Example:

```
public class MyTest
{
    public void TestContainer()
    {
        var parentContext = MyContainer.Container.GetInstance<MyContext>();
        TestParentAndChildContext(parentContext); 
    }

    private void TestParentAndChildContext(MyContext parentContext)
    {
        var childContext = MyContainer.Container.GetInstance<MyContext>();
        Assert.AreEqual(parentContext, childContext);
    }
}

public class MyContainer
{
    public static Container Container
    {
        get { return container ?? (container = RegisterAndVerifyContainer()); }
    }

    private static Container RegisterAndVerifyContainer()
    {
        var container = new Container();
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new ExecutionContextScopeLifestyle();
        container.Register<DbContext, MyContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

        container.Verify();

        return container;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Simple Injector you register an implementation by its abstraction. In your case you registed an `MyContext` by its `DbContext` base type. From this point on Simple Injector will know that it will need to construct a `MyContext` in case someone asks for a `DbContext`. This is the whole purpose of

> Program to an interface, not an implementation

In your case however, although you do register the `MyContext` by its abstraction, you request a new instance of `MyContext` directly, instead of requesting it through its abstraction. This causes Simple Injector to look for the `MyContext` in its list of registered abstractions. Since there is no registration for `MyContext` (there is for `DbContext` though, but that's a totally different type what Simple Injector is concerned), Simple Injector will try to add the missing registration. This succeeds because `MyContext` is concrete and has single resolvable constructor, while you are using Simple Injector v4.x.

By default the older versions of Simple Injector will resolve unregistered concrete types as `Transient`. This default changed in v5, where it won't create any unregistered concrete type by default.

So `MyContext` is resolved as transient when requested directly. You can solve this by changing your test to the following:

```
public void TestContainer()
{
    using (MyContainer.Container.BeginExecutionContextScope()) {
        var parentContext = MyContainer.Container.GetInstance<DbContext>();
        TestParentAndChildContext(parentContext); 
    }
}

private void TestParentAndChildContext(MyContext parentContext)
{
    var childContext = MyContainer.Container.GetInstance<DbContext>();
    Assert.AreEqual(parentContext, childContext);
}
```

Do note that Simple Injector usually detects these kinds of mistakes. In case you register `MyContext` by its `DbContext` base type, but inject `MyContext` directly in a constructor of a type, Simple Injector will throw a [Short-Circuited Dependency](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ShortCircuitedDependencies.html) error when calling `Verify()`.

The reason you didn't get warned about this, is because you've called `Verify()` before the resolve action (you should typically not call `GetInstance` from within your application; instead you should build all object graphs up front). But when you'd call `Verify` (again) after resolving `MyContext` you would see the exception popping up:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestContainer()
{
    var container = MyContainer.Container.GetInstance<DbContext>();
    var parentContext = container.GetInstance<MyContext>();
    var childContext = container.GetInstance<MyContext>();

    // This call will fail
    container.Verify();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge.
I still have a lot to learn, what would you say it is the best option in my case? I have limited access to the presentation layer, we work under the business layer and data layer and need to share the same context while executing some business rules. All projects are class libraries.
How could I not call GetInstance from my business logic and build up the graphs beforehand?

Comment: @Lucus: You don't call `GetInstance`. You register all objects in the startup path of the application (the Compostion Root). And all instances are received using constructor injection. You build deep object grapns.